# ArcGIS / ArcMap problem with tiff file and projection

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I have a raster in ArcMap .

The projection is WGS 1984 UTM 22.

When I look the details of the projection I can see that the "scale factor" is 0.9996

When I save this raster in a in tif file and the scale factor become 1 
When I save this raster in a in img file and the scale factor  stay 0.9996.

This is anoying me because when I open the file in others softwares they do not recognize the  projection.

My version is Armap 10.0 Build 2414

Does anyone already has this problem and have a solution ?

Comment: What process did you use to save the raster from `img` to `tif`?  The projection is not something that usually changes, so it seems there may be some outside influence.  Also, do you have the ability to upgrade to the most current version of ArcGIS?  You are quite a bit behind at this point, and sometimes weird stuff crops up with older versions.

Comment: I found a reference to a similar issue in 10.1 (nim087078) but it hasn't been fixed yet. What happens if you define the coordinate system (projection) of the tiff file after the conversion?

Comment: A difference between a scale factor of 0.9996 and 1 is insignifficant.

Comment: I'am facing the same problem, same Version!!!  (Armap 10.0 Build 2414)

Comment: E.g. if I project a raster from WGS84 to UTM 34 as tif the scale factor gets corrupted. And there is no way to overwrite the projection of the output (like Define Projection). I switched to img as output format, which is a poor workaround. Looks like updating is the solution. @ A.S. a scale factor difference between 0.9996 an 1 is very significant, at least using UTM at 50 degree latitude.